# open csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file with a variable number of lines. The columns are called id, date, time, and name.

```
id date time name
01 02.02 1200 Max
02 02.02 1400 Alexx
03 03.02 1600 John
```

I need to write a Python script that will open this file and create dictionaries, the name of which will be the value of the id column and the content of the key-value pair date, time, and name. Like here id03 = {'date': '03.02', 'time': '1600', 'name': 'John'}

```
import csv

with open("freeCards.csv", 'r') as file:
    reader_object = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="\t")
    new_card = {}
    for row in reader_object:
        new_card[row['id']] = {
        'date': row['date'],
        'time': row['time'],
        'name': row['name']
    }
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work, specifically?

Comment: Fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: Are you sure the delimiter is TAB, not space?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open("freeCards.csv", 'r') as file:
    reader_object = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter="\t")
    new_cards = {}
    for row in reader_object:
        new_card = {
            'date': row['date'],
            'time': row['time'],
            'name': row['name']
        }
        new_cards[row['id']] = new_card
```

- `new_cards` is used as a dictionary to store all the cards, with keys as the id `values` and values as dictionaries containing the `date`, `time`, and `name` values.
- `new_card` is created as a dictionary within the loop to store the `date`, `time` and `name` values for each row.
- `row['id']` is used as the key to store `new_card` in `new_cards` dictionary.

Make sure that the delimiter used in `csv.DictReader()` matches the actual delimiter used in your CSV file. In the example above it's set to `\t`, but your CSV file may use a different delimiter such as `,` or `;`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this, but why would this work if OP's original code does not?

Answer (score 0):

Use space(`" "`) as delimiter.

```
cat freeCards.csv
id date time name
01 02.02 1200 Max
02 02.02 1400 Alexx
03 03.02 1600 John

import csv

with open("freeCards.csv", 'r', newline='') as file:
    reader_object = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=" ")
    new_card = {}
    for row in reader_object:
        new_card[row['id']] = {
        'date': row['date'],
        'time': row['time'],
        'name': row['name']
    }

new_card

{'01': {'date': '02.02', 'time': '1200', 'name': 'Max'},
 '02': {'date': '02.02', 'time': '1400', 'name': 'Alexx'},
 '03': {'date': '03.02', 'time': '1600', 'name': 'John'}}
```